# What are the bracket numbers in a patent?

Tags: patent-applications

Example
[image: Patent]

You see how the **United States** Has a (19) in brackets. What do that mean? I see on othet patents the United States patent is also (19) and inventor is also matched up with (76) or (75) and invention titles bracket with (54). Do this has a special meaning? I just want to know ever inch of patents & there meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are INID numbers, which most countries use to identify the nature of each field in a patent publication. These are defined in [WIPO standard ST.9](http://www.wipo.int/export/sites/www/standards/en/pdf/03-09-01.pdf).

For example, 19 refers to the identifier of the office publishing the document.